# Getting file out of url with php

Tags: php, ajax, xml

So I give my users the possibility to upload a xml file of their iTunes playlist. Once they've uploaded their xml-file, i need to read out that xml file. I tried it first with just an ajax call and a local xml file and it worked fine, but now i need to get acces to the uploaded xml file. 
This is my upload form

```
<form id="formulier" action="playlist.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Upload your playlist</legend>
        </br>
        <label>
            <input type="file" name="bestand">
        </label>
        </br>
        </br>
        <input type="submit" value="Generate">
</fieldset>
```

this is my playlist.php file:

```
<?php
$path = "playlists/" . ($_FILES['bestand']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bestand']['tmp_name'], $path)){
}
header("Location:index.html?url=".$path);
?>
```

this is my ajax call that i previously used:

```
var my_fn = function(callback) {   // <-- this is callback to be called later
var jax = [];
$.ajax({
    url: "",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (data) {
        var song = $(data).find('key').filter(function () {
            return $(this).text().indexOf('Name') != -1;
        }).each(function() {
            var content = $(this).next('string').text();
            jax.push(content);
        });
        callback(jax);   
    }
});
};
```

How do I get to read out the xml file that is uploaded by the user? I really do not have a clue...

Comment: Looks like you have the AJAX in place.. what part is not working?

Comment: the part where i read out the xml file that the user has uploaded. I don't know how to read out the file that they upload with my php code

Comment: How is the javascript related to the upload, are you using ajax to upload your file or are you doing a normal form submission and is the javascript part of the next page?

Comment: I am using a form in my body to upload a file that i then save in a folder that i've created. I learned that i can read out files that are stored locally with ajax, but i don't know how to get my data out of the php link

Comment: jeroen, ik zie dat je Nederlands spreekt?

Comment: Yep, not here though...

Comment: You can get the query string of the current page with `location.search` and take it from there.

Comment: So all you're trying to do is read a file using PHP? Not sure I get what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: So the user exports his itunes playlist as xml file, then uses my upload button to load the xml file up, then presses generate and my site generates a word cloud with al the songtitles